# Select all values by pattern from redis server using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I had a multiple chanel like this

```
client.HMSET('live:user:1', {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "1"
});
client.HMSET('live:user:2', {
    "a": "2",
    "b": "2"
});
client.HMSET('live:user:3', {
    "a": "3",
    "b": "3"
});

client.HMSET('otherchanel:user:4', {
    "a": "4",
    "b": "4"
});
client.HMSET('otherchanel:user:5', {
    "a": "5",
    "b": "5"
});
client.HMSET('otherchanel:user:6', {
    "a": "6",
    "b": "6"
});
```

How can i select all values by key pattern "live:*"? I need it to retern JSON object to my client app like this:

```
[{user:1, a:1, b:1}, {user:2, a:2, b:2}, {user:3, a:3, b:3}]
```

Comment: did you try client.get('live:*')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, but you have to also fetch all the keys and combine them. I suggest using async to make the calls asynchronous:

```
function getAllUsersInChannel_suboptimal(channelName, functionCallback) {
client.keys(channelName + ":user:*", function(err, userKeys) {
    if (!err) {
        async.map(userKeys, 
            function(userKey, callback) {
                client.hgetall(userKey, function(err, user) {
                    if (!err) {
                        callback(null, user);
                    }
                    else {
                        callback(err);
                    }
                });
            }, 
            function(err, userList) {
                if (!err) {
                    functionCallback(null, userList);
                }
                else {
                    functionCallback(err);
                }
            });
    }
    else {
        functionCallback(err);
    }
});
}
```

Using a pattern match can drastically reduce performance even on medium sized databases. I suggest you also index the id's of the users using a set.

Create the counter key if it does not exist and set its value to 0:

```
SETNX <channel_name>:user:counter 0
```

When you add a new user, first increment the counter key, which also fetches its value:

```
INCR <channel_name>:user:counter => <new_id>
```

This will yield the new id for the user. Now you have to save a new member in the "user:index" set like so:

```
SADD <channel_name>:user:index <new_id>
```

You can now add the new user key like so:

```
HMSET <channel_name>:user:<new_id> <list of values>
```

To fetch data for all users you would first get a the list of existing users like so:

```
SMEMBERS <channel_name>:user:index => <list of all user ids>
```

For each id you would have to fetch the hash values:

```
asynchronous each <list of all user ids> as <user_id>
HGETALL channel_name>:user:<user_id> => all values of key
end asynchronous each
```

In Node.js, considering that you've already used the techniques above to index users, you retrieve all users in a channel using something like this:

```
function getAllUsersInChannel_optimal(channelName, functionCallback) {
client.smembers(channelName + ":user:index", function(err, userIds) {
    if (!err) {
        async.map(userIds, 
            function(userId, callback) {
                client.hgetall(channelName + ":user:" + userId, function(err, user) {
                    if (!err) {
                        callback(null, user);
                    }
                    else {
                        callback(err);
                    }
                });
            }, 
            function(err, userList) {
                if (!err) {
                    functionCallback(null, userList);
                }
                else {
                    functionCallback(err);
                }
            });
    }
    else {
        functionCallback(err);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To get all keys with a pattern use

```
client.keys('live:*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You forgot a closing `)` :)

Answer (score 4):

Using client.keys() is very inefficient and raises CPU spikes, it is not advised to use it in the production environment. If there is a lot of data stored in the Redis you should consider client.scan() method which will fetch the keys in batches. It will also reduce memory usages if the number of the keys are a lot.